# Triple HEX code to RGB

Tags: php, hex, rgb

I'm having toubles with **converting *triple* HEX color codes in** an **RGB color code**.

What I've got so far for **HEX to RGB** is:

```
if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
        $color['r'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 1) . $r);
        $color['g'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 1, 1) . $g);
        $color['b'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 1) . $b);
    }
```

When I convert the RGB code back to HEX it's a different one.

E.g.: `#FFF becomes 15, 15, 15` but `15, 15, 15 is #0F0F0F`

I'm also not sure about converting RGB back to triple HEX code. My code for **RGB to HEX** looks like this:

```
$hex = str_pad(dechex($r), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$hex.= str_pad(dechex($g), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$hex.= str_pad(dechex($b), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like "taking off the padding" would get it back? You need to know in advance if you are going to output 3 or 6: if you output 6, scale each component by 16. Some browsers might not support 3, so I would always emit 6.

Comment: So that's how I get RGB back to HEX, right? But what about the wrong RGB code from a triple HEX code?

Comment: @pst should that be an answer instead of a comment? Put a little more work into explaining that comment and you could get some nice reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to handle triplets in a different way: #XYZ = #XXYYZZ. #FFF should be, for example, the same as #FFFFFF, or well, (255, 255, 255), instead of (15, 15, 15).

So, a way to do this is with the following code:

```
if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
    $color['r'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 1) . substr($hex, 0, 1));
    $color['g'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 1, 1) . substr($hex, 1, 1));
    $color['b'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 1) . substr($hex, 2, 1));
}
```

Note I'm not including $r, $g and $b, as I don't know why are you using them.

Answer (score 2):

```
function hex2rgb($hex)
{
    // Ensure we're working only with upper-case hex values,
    // toss out any extra characters.
    $hex = preg_replace('/[^A-F0-9]/', '', strtoupper($hex));

    // Convert 3-letter hex RGB codes into 6-letter hex RGB codes
    $hex_len = strlen($hex);
    if ($hex_len == 3) {
        $new_hex = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $hex_len; ++$i) {
            $new_hex .= $hex[$i].$hex[$i];
        }
        $hex = $new_hex;
    }

    // Calculate the RGB values
    $rgb['r'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 2));
    $rgb['g'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 2));
    $rgb['b'] = hexdec(substr($hex, 4, 2));

    return $rgb;
}

print_r(hex2rgb('#fff'));      // r: 255 g: 255 b: 255
print_r(hex2rgb('#AE9C00'));   // r: 174 g: 156 b: 0
```